# Loop through array

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have records in `list.txt` (INPUT) as

```
List of animals SET 1=Dog 2=Crow 3=Snake Pet,bird,reptile
List of Countries SET 1=France 2=Singapore 3=Columbia Europe,Asia,SouthAmerica
List of Parts SET 1=KeyBoard 2=Speaker 3=LEDpanel Computer,AudioPlayer,Television
List of Cities SET 1=Amsterdam 2=KualLumpur 3=Paris Netherlands,Malaysia,France
```

Want the last column of each line to be used as array for replacing the numbers 1,2,3
For eg. Use `Pet,bird,reptile` of first line to make `Pet=Dog` `bird=Crow` and `reptile=Snake`.

So, the OUTPUT file would be

```
List of animals SET Pet=Dog bird=Crow reptile=Snake
List of Countries SET Europe=France Asia=Singapore SouthAmerica=Columbia
List of Parts SET Computer=KeyBoard AudioPlayer=Speaker Television=LEDpanel
List of Cities SET Netherlands=Amsterdam Malaysia=KualLumpur France=Paris
```

Using `awk`, I could split the last column as string of array.
But unable to use the same to replace the numbers 1,2,3.

Answer (score 1):

You can loop over items in an awk array `a` using the syntax `for (i in a)`. So for example you could do something like

```
awk '{split($NF,a,","); $NF=""; for (i in a) sub(i"=",a[i]"=",$0); print}' list.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

If there are always 3 items (`x=y`) and no space in the lines, this `awk` statement should work:

```
awk -F',| |=' '{printf "%s %s %s %s %s=%s %s=%s %s=%s\n", \
$1, $2, $3, $4, $11, $6, $12, $8, $13, $10}' list.txt
```

**Explanation:**

- `-F',| |='`: set the field separator to `,`, space and `=`
- `'{printf ...` print the values in the desired format
- `list.txt` the input file

Answer (score 0):

This script should work for any number of items in a row.

> `while read line 
>   do 
>       valType=($(echo $line | awk '{ print $NF }' | tr ',' ' '))
>       vals=($(echo $line | awk '{ $NF="";$1="";$2="";$3="";$4="";  print $0 }' | tr [1234567890] ' ' | tr '=' ' ' ))
>       echo $line | awk '{print $1" "$2" "$3" "$4 }' | tr -d '\n'
>       numVals=${#vals[@]}
>       for i in $(seq 0 $((numVals-1)))
>       do
>           echo -n " "${valType[$i]}"="${vals[$i]}
>       done
>       echo " "
>   done < list.txt`

Explanation:

`valType` contains an array of the comma seperated elements.

`vals` contains the associated values between the 4th and last positions in the row, with numbers and equals signs removed.

Looping through the number of values in the arrays, the matching values in both arrays can be referenced.

Answer (score 0):

```
set '.\(=.[^ ]*\) ' '\([^,]*\),'
sed "s/\$/,/;s/$1$1$1$2$2$2/\4\1 \5\2 \6\3/
" <<\DATA
List of animals SET 1=Dog 2=Crow 3=Snake Pet,bird,reptile
List of Countries SET 1=France 2=Singapore 3=Columbia Europe,Asia,SouthAmerica
List of Parts SET 1=KeyBoard 2=Speaker 3=LEDpanel Computer,AudioPlayer,Television
List of Cities SET 1=Amsterdam 2=KualLumpur 3=Paris Netherlands,Malaysia,France
DATA
```

That uses the shell array to set your array.

#### OUTPUT

```
List of animals SET Pet=Dog bird=Crow reptile=Snake
List of Countries SET Europe=France Asia=Singapore SouthAmerica=Columbia
List of Parts SET Computer=KeyBoard AudioPlayer=Speaker Television=LEDpanel
List of Cities SET Netherlands=Amsterdam Malaysia=KualLumpur France=Paris
```